# How to set title in html, from TS file ANGULAR

Tags: angular

I want to display in my html page the title saying. "My name is " in which name value is coming form my query params

```
  queryParams() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((param) => {
      this.firstName =param["first_name"];
     });
  }


title="My name is ${this.firstName} "
```

title is getting displayed, but not able to pass the value of first name in it

Comment: try writing `<div> My name is {{firstName}} </div>` in your HTML file

Comment: this.route.queryParams.subscribe((param) => {
      this.firstName =param["first_name"];
      title = `My name is ${this.firstName}`;
     });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
queryParams() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((param) => {
      this.firstName =param["first_name"];
      this.title = "My name is ${this.firstName} "
     });
}
```

Or you can display in your html like:

```
<div>My name is {{firstName}}</div>
```

Comment: You don't even need the line: `this.title = "My name is ${this.firstName}"` as you're not using the title variable in the html but only the firstName via two-way-binding.

Comment: these are two alternatives method he can try